# 2 ViewControllers presenting a UITabBarController Modally

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram, presentmodalviewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I'm trying to create a functionality in an iOS app that is similar to Instagram's camera "TabBarItem" functionality. When the camera button is pressed, the `tabBarController` dismisses itself (modally) and a camera view is displayed in the background. When we decide to dismiss the camera view, the `tabBarController` is presented modally and all is good! My question is similar to this implementation.

I have a customized `UITabBar` where 2 "TabBarItems" should perform the action described above. So when one "TabBarItem" is pressed, the `tabBarController` should dismiss (modally) and a View should be present in the background as the `tabBarController` is being dismissed. The same should happen with the other "TabBarItem" but with a different view showing up. I've thought of a couple different methods of doing this but none of them seem really "elegant" and I haven't found a similar question on SO. So here goes.

For the purposes of describing it easier:

TabBarItem1 (TB1) is pressed -> TabBarController dismisses (modally) -> ViewController1 (VC1) is shown (as TabBarController is being dismissed)

TabBarItem2 (TB2) is pressed -> TabBarController dismisses (modally) -> ViewController2 (VC2) is shown (as TabBarController is being dismissed)

**1st Method:**
Set VC1 as the initialVC -> present VC2 modally (animated:NO) -> which presents TabBarController modally
Then, when...
TB1 pressed -> Dismiss TabBarController (animated:YES) -> Dismiss VC2 (animated:NO)
**PROBLEM**: VC2 will be visible until TabBarController is dismissed. So this is a no go.

**2nd Method:**
Create a ViewController (which is set as the initialVC) that contains 2 UIViews (representing VC1.view & VC2.view) that are hidden/displayed based on the TabBarItem selected. This SEEMS like the most reasonable solution. But I don't think this is very elegant. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions. Hopefully, it's not as confusing as I made it seem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you do method #1 and dismiss VC2 (without dismissing the tab bar yourself first) does dismiss both in the stack with the correct appearance? I haven't kept up with the modal stack documentation, but I think that might work.

You may have a little cleanup to do when you need to put the tab bar back (although I think it should return when you re-present vc2.)